# Referencing fields in an array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, moodle

This is a really simple question which I'm struggling with.  I have a variable ($foo) which is an array created from a sql call.

When I am referencing a field in code what is the difference between

`$foo['bar']` and `$foo->bar` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$foo['bar']
```

references an element with the key 'bar' in an array assigned to the variable $foo, as retrieved by mysql_fetch_array()

```
$foo->bar
```

references the property called 'bar' in an object instance in the variable $foo, as retrieved by mysql_fetch_object()

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the mysqli_fetch_* method you use.

- mysqli_fetch_object -> $foo->bar
- mysqli_fetch_assoc -> $foo['bar']
- mysqli_fetch_array -> $foo[0]

'Assoc' stands for 'associated (array)'.

Answer (score 0):

$foo['bar'] is used to access array index 
this case $foo is an array variable 
and 
$foo->bar  is used to access class method . in this case $foo is a class object

```
$foo = new StdClass();
$foo->bar = "Anything";
```

or

```
$foo['bar'] = "dfgdfG";
```